# Error al instalar laravel/ui laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, npm, sass, artisan

estoy tratando de instalar el paquete laravel/ui para laravel version 6, he seguido la documentacion del paquete y todo me funciona bien salvo un ultimo paso.

al ejecutar el comando `php artisan ui vue` o `php artisan ui react` pide realizar al final `npm install && npm run dev`

Cuando ejecuto npm run dev me aparece el siguiente error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                          4:16:06 ├F10: PM┤
 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'outputStyle'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:98:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\6\tutorial1\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

no se si tenga que ver con sass pero no he podido encontrar una solucion a este problema. Agradecere a la persona que sepa solucionarlo.

la estructura de mi package.json esta asi:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

y estoy usando node en su version 12.18.0

Comment: por favor, pega el mensaje como texto. No nos corresponde transcribir el que se ve en las imágenes

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ he corregido la pregunta, espero que ahora tenga un visto bueno gracias

Comment: Bien! Sería útil que agregues a la pregunta el contenido del archivo `package.json` y la versión de node que estás usando.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya actualize la informacion

Comment: Puedes probar bajando la version de sass-loader a la 7.1.0 `npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader` y `npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0` como la mayoría sugiere en [este hilo](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2206#issuecomment-527730992). U otra opción sería actualizar la versión de laravel-mix a la 5, pues [mas adelante](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2206#issuecomment-534776908) dicen que esto se ha solucionado con v5.0.0

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ si ya me funciono bajandolo a la version 7.1.0 gracias